Очередь для nodejs
Есть запрос и длительная функция. Клиент переодически стукает в урл и получает прогресс выполнения этой функции.
Стартует длинная функция сейчас через process.nextTick. Но так как клиентов может быть несколько - хочется поставить задания в очередь. Есть ли аналог питонского Queue?
В продакшн процессов станет несколько. Как передать статус между процессами?
Интересно обойтись без редиса.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/process-pool

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html эта штука не может вернуть состояние задачи по идентификатору, не так ли? вот, кмк, лучший аналог https://npmjs.com/package/p-queue.  вот, https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull лучшее решение для того чтобы состояние было доступно между процессам, но там нужен бекенд в виде редиса или постгри. можно... написать микросервис, который будет выполнять тяжелую бизнес-логику внутри worker-ов и сам в себе хранить очередь на p-queue. вообще легко )

@nörbörnën обратно там можно через глобальную переменную сработать.

не оч понятно к чему относится комментарий

коментарий к питону

ну так с p-queue можно тоже написать такое, с переменной в которой Map или LRU cache. могу показать, не делаю этого из-за того что в вопросе говорится про вариант с несколькими экземплярами бекенда
